# How do I gather geolocation data on GitHub users in a week's time, given their API rate limiting constraints?

Tags: github

To make a long story short, I need to gather geolocation data and signup date on ~23 million GitHub users for a historical data visualization project. I need to do this within a week's time.

I'm rate-limited to 5000 API calls/hour while authenticated. This is a very generous rate limit, but unfortunately, I've run into a major issue.

The GitHub API's "get all users" feature is great (it gives me around 30-50 users per API call, paginated), but it **doesn't return the complete user information I need**.

If you look at the following call (https://api.github.com/users?since=0), and compare it to a call to retrieve one user's information (https://api.github.com/users/mojombo), you'll notice that **only the user-specific call retrieves the information I need** such as `"created_at": "2007-10-20T05:24:19Z"` and `"location": "San Francisco"`.

This means that I would have to make 1 API call per user to get the data I need. Processing 23,000,000 users then requires 4,600 hours or a little over half a year. I don't have that much time!

Are there any workarounds to this, or any other ways to get geolocation and sign up timestamp data of all GitHub users? If the paginated get all users API route returned full user info, it'd be smooth sailing.

Comment: Ask Github for a temporary increase in your rate limit for your research. Or perhaps you can ask them to give you a data dump. [I've had success getting an increase in my storage limit.](https://github.com/gitpan)

Comment: @Schwern Okay! I just sent a GitHub a contact ticket linking them to this SO post. Hopefully everything will turn out well. But in case that falls through, is there really no other way?

Comment: @Schwern I finished my project! Since you helped me out, I thought you might have wanted to check out the finished product: https://joshuarli.github.io/GitHubLog/

Comment: Excellent! Pretty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious in the API. It's probably specifically designed to make mass data collection very slow. There's a few things you could do to try and speed this up.

## [Increase the page size](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination)

In your https://api.github.com/users?since=0 call add `per_page=100`. That will cut the number of calls getting the whole user list by 1/3.

## Randomly sample the user list.

With a set of 23 million people you don't need to poll very single one to get good data about Github signup and location patterns. Since you're sampling the entire population randomly there's no poll bias to account for.

If user 1200 signed up on 2015-10-10 and user 1235 also signed up on 2015-10-10 then you know users 1201 to 1234 also signed up on 2015-10-10. I'm going to assume you don't need any more granularity than that.

Location can also be randomly sampled. If you randomly sample 1 in 10 users, or even 1 in 100 (one per page). 230,000 out of 23 million is a *great* polling sample. Professional national polls in the US have sample sizes of a few thousand people for an even bigger population.

## How Much Sampling Can You Do In A Week?

A week gives you 168 hours or 840,000 requests.

You can get 1 user or 1 page of 100 users per request. Getting all the users, at 100 users per request, is 230,000 requests. That leaves you with 610,000 requests for individual users or about 1 in 37 users.

I'd go with 1 in 50 to account for download and debugging time. So you can poll two random users per page or about 460,000 out of 23 million. This is an *excellent* sample size.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all your time and help! Using random sampling certainly didn't occur to me in the first place. It definitely sacrifices accuracy, but in this case with such a large quantity of users, 460K out of 23M should be fairly representative. I'll see if I can pull this off :) It'd still be nice if GitHub could give me more API requests though to expedite the entire process!